# DITA XSLT writing techniques

Tags: xml, xslt, dita

I want to customize a DITA xml plugin to transform my file into a new XML format. e.g: MusicXML.

I have tried to write a valid XSLT to transform my file,
however applied the xslt I wrote to the plugin in the DITA-OT, I did not get the expected output file.

Are there any instructions that can provide guidance to start writing my first DITA XSLT file.

XSLT file in other plugins, I find the code as following:

```
<xsl:call-template name="setStandardAttr">
  <xsl:with-param name="IDPrefix" select="'dl'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

However, I didn't find a template named setStandardAttr and how this code can call that template? Or it is a built-in template?

Comment: is there any imported or included file in main XSLT which you have?

Comment: With the DITA OT, the problem could come from many places, but there's not enough info in your post to suggest where to look. What exactly were you expecting as output, and what was your input? You can look at the log generated by the OT for clues. If you're sure it's XSLT, you can try running it outside of the DITA OT, to remove that complexity. The docs for the OT itself are here (choose your version): https://www.dita-ot.org/3.2/

Comment: @AmrendraKumar I post another issue that is related to this question. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717294/xslt-fails-to-transform-dita-into-new-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT is a programming language. When I want to start coding in a new programming language, I usually start by buying a good book on the subject and skim reading it from cover to cover.

So yes, there are instructions. There are books and tutorials, and online specifications. And when you've read them, and written your first program, and it doesn't do what you expect, then you can post your code here and ask why, and we can explain.

Reading other people's code can also be a good learning aid, and it seems you're doing that. This bit of code is calling a user-written template named setStandardAttr; if you can't find it then that's because you're looking in the wrong place.